# Jazz guitar: thin tone on strings 1-2

Tags: electric-guitar, technique, tone, string-gauge

Hi jazz guitar experts -

I'm able to get a nice warm, muted, jazzy tone on strings 3-6, but not 1-2. This persists across different guitars, amps, and tone settings. For example, I've tried

Heritage semi-hollow body + Fender blues jr

Strat + Vox modeling amp

I can get the tone pretty warm and rich on strings 3-6 by carefully tuning all the pots, pickup switch, reverb, EQ, etc, but strings 1-2 are just thin and tinny. Especially on a Strat.

What's going on? Strings too light?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried tuning pickup height or string height? Usually you’d want the pickups to be slightly closer to the strings on the treble side than on the bass side. Having a high distance will lead to a bright, tinny sound, having a small distance will lead to a beefy sound. Try to find the best distance so that your guitar sounds good and balanced. Also it might be that your top two strings are set up very high, which would as well increase the distance to the pickups.

Comment: I'll try this, thanks! I always like my action as low as possible anyway so hopefully that will work out

Comment: The action height affects also how much room the string has to vibrate. Low frequencies have highest amplitude for the same loudness so they are muted first. I've understood that jazz players often prefer high action for the tone.

Comment: @ojs Somewhat. The biggest problem with low action is that it may cause lots of fretbuzz. The problems with high action are: It requires more movement, the intonation gets harder to get right and the notes high on the fretboard might become louder to to getting closer to the pickups. Depending on what you play certain things are more important, but usually simply going high or going low will give you many problems. You need to find a good compromise.

Comment: Are you sure you are lecturing to the right person?

Comment: So supposing I'm looking for action as low as possible without buzz, with a rich, warm, classic jazz guitar timbre, what should I do? Are those goals somewhat in opposition?

Comment: @user2556667 raising your pickup on one side is not the same as lowering the action. Generally the better the neck is done the less buzz you get, meaning you can go for lower action. But in the end you always need to find a compromise.

Answer (score 0):

You really should say what strings are on! Then we've got something to work on!

The gauge of strings anywhere on guitar will affect the sound they produce - thicker meaning richer, more body, and often a little more sustain. So if you're using .010" for your top string, go to .013".

Be aware also that new strings will have that brightness that you maybe want to avoid. So play them in over a period of weeks and hear the difference.

An eq pedal helped me find a more jazzy sound, tapering off the higher frequencies.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to consider is that on a typical string set used for jazz guitar strings 3-6 are wound and strings 1 are 2 are not. Wound strings, especially flat wounds have a different tonal characteristic than solid strings. I don’t have a surefire solution for that. Maybe you can not change the top strings as often to let them mellow out over time. Experiment with different gauges and materials too. You mentioned trying different guitars amps and tone settings but not different strings.